# My Identity Is What I Am. So What Am I?

Tags: riddle, science

---

You hear me all the time

Yet I am not sound

You see me all the time

Yet I cannot be seen

You use me all the time

Yet you do not realize it

I created your world

Yet most ignore me

I am always everywhere

Yet always in one place

I am always white

Yet I am also black

---

What hath be my identity?

UPDATE: Just a slight error that I made-The title was meant to say what, not who. So we are looking for a physical obect. Take a look at the answr that has air. It is not correct, but it has the right idea.

Comment: do you mean  Yet I cannot be seen instead of seem?

Comment: "What hath be" is ungrammatical in any version of English - is that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is:

> Air

line 1-2:

> You hear me all the time Yet I am not sound

means:

> The movements of the particles in the air are something that can be heard but we can not hear it because of the constant noise around us (there are special quiet rooms where you can hear the moving air)

line 3-4:

> You see me all the time Yet I cannot be seen

means:

> We seem to see the air all the time, but we really do not see it because it is transparent

line 5-6:

> You use me all the time Yet you do not realize it

means:

> We breathe all the time and use the air but we do not think about it and we see it for granted

line 7-8:

> I created your world Yet most ignore me

means:

> Air is the one that allows life on earth, but we ignore it and continue to create air pollution

line 9-10:

> I am always everywhere Yet always in one place

means:

> It is everywhere in the world, but it is still in one place that is the Earth and is not in the rest of the stars in the universe

line 11-12:

> I am always white Yet I am also black

means:

> It has no color but can get color according to the circumstances when there is:a fog is - air's color is white, a soot is -air's color is black

Answer (score 4):

My Identity Is Who I Am. So Who Am I?

> I am your mind.

**You hear me all the time, yet I am not sound**

> I can hear the thoughts and the voice in my mind but it doesn't make an actual sound.

**You see me all the time, yet I cannot be seen**

> I can picture in my mind what my it thinks but it's just imagination, I can't see it outside of my mind but I can have an idea that I can eventually "see" (maybe it's more appropriate if I say "imagine")

**You use me all the time, yet you do not realize it**

> I can see what's in my mind (or as I said before, I can imagine it) but I can't physically see it.

**I created your world, yet most ignore me**

> Without our mind we wouldn't exist, since we wouldn't be able to think and do other basic stuff, so our mind determines what and who we are, but nobody can see it.

**I am always everywhere, yet always in one place**

> We can think of being in a lot of places at the same time, or anyway, we can think of a lot of things and this makes our mind space between different places at the same time. That's why we can say our mind is everywhere. But at the end of the day it's still always inside us.

**I am always white, yet I am also black**

> This might refer to the fact that we might be in a positive or negative state of mind. Or that our mind can either be pure or evil. Or that it might be active, smart, clear or lazy.

What hath be my identity?

> I suppose it's my mind or my imagination or both.

Answer (score 1):

My Identity Is Who I Am. So Who Am I?

> I don't have a separate identity than the person to who I belong. I am your *conscience*.

You hear me all the time

Yet I am not sound

> Figuratively you hear it (inner voice) though it is not explicitly *sounded*.

You see me all the time

Yet I cannot be seen

> Again, figuratively you can notice your conscience trying to guide you though it cannot literally be *seen*.

You use me all the time

Yet you do not realize it

> Heeding to conscience happens all the time though subconsciously.

I created your world

Yet most ignore me

> The world you *sense* around you is a sensation created by me (in my sense of [*consciousness*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/conscience)) yet most of you do not even acknowledge my presence.

I am always everywhere

Yet always in one place

> I am with you wherever you go, but am always in the single place where you are.

I am always white

Yet I am also black

> Mostly I am [associated with *positive* guidance but I may mislead sometimes](http://www.philosophypages.com/dy/c7.htm#consc).

What hath be my identity?

> Not sure if this is a hint in some way.